# Calling another clause in Prolog with same clause name

Tags: prolog, clause

For an assignment I am required to create a rule based system to test compliance with a fire_code

roomHasFastExit is my test clause where the others are part of a building plan

Rm is equal to wotl1 in this case

```
roomHasFastExit(Rm):- hasDoor(Rm, Door), isa(Door, outsideDoor).

hasDoor(wolt1, wodoorlt1c).
hasDoor(wolt1, wodoorlt1exit).
hasDoor(wolt1, wodoor115lt1).

isa(wodoor115lt1, door).
isa(wodoorlt1c, door).
isa(wodoorlt1exit, outsideDoor).
```

The problem I am occurring is if find that the door I have requested does not comply, I need to check the next door, if I recursively call the clause I will just get the same door, So how do I loop through each door checking if it is compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Your code it's already ok:

```
?- roomHasFastExit(Rm).
Rm = wolt1 ;
false.
```

When you really need to '*loop through each*' record of your *database*, you are rather evaluating each possible alternative that satisfies your query.

In Prolog this relational point of view is obtained by means of *backtracking*, that allows exaustive search in top down order.

At interpreter top level you implements this using ';'

```
?- hasDoor(wolt1,X).
X = wodoorlt1c ;
X = wodoorlt1exit ;
X = wodoor115lt1.
```

A useful library predicate that forces a full evaluation is [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2. For instance

```
show_available_doors(Room) :-
    forall(hasDoor(Room, Door), writeln(Door)).
```

outputs:

```
?- show_available_doors(wolt1).
wodoorlt1c
wodoorlt1exit
wodoor115lt1
```

Prolog uses *lists* as main syntactic construct when expressing algorithms: [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)/3 it's the simpler builtin that *constructs* lists, fully evaluating queries:

```
?- findall(Door, hasDoor(Room, Door), Doors).
Doors = [wodoorlt1c, wodoorlt1exit, wodoor115lt1].
```